# Keyboard write wrong characters windows 10

Tags: windows-10, keyboard

My Keyboard start typing wrong characters when I press shift key

like Shift + 2 -> " and it should be @

Can any one please tell me what is the problem ?

Comment: You have the wrong keyboard layout installed.

Answer (score 3):

Press left alt + right shift

For a permanent solution, set your keyboard language to US international (i assume this is the layout of your keyboard)

In Windows 10 you go to settings -> Time & Language -> Region & Language -> click the current language (mine is English US) -> Options

And here you have keyboards, add the desired layout (probably US QWERTY) and remove the other layout